# Terraform : Remove duplicates from map based on value

Tags: terraform, tuples

I have a tuples which are mapped to a local variable

```
locals {
  my_val = [
    {
      region = "us-east-1"
      value  = 1000
      data = 3000
    },
    {
      region = "us-east-1"
      value = 1001
      data = 4000
    },
    {
      region = "us-east2"
      value = 1002
      data = 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to remove the duplicates based on the value of the pair, here I want to place the condition for region `us-east-1` and the output should be

```
{
my_val = [
    {
      region = "us-east-1"
      value  = 1000
      data = 3000
    },
    {
      region = "us-east2"
      value = 1002
      data = 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

Need help in applying distinct on a value of a map object.

Comment: Maybe a combination of `flatten` (https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten) and `distinct` (https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/distinct)?

Comment: Tried and didn't succeed @MarkoE

Comment: And would you mind adding a bit more context, i.e., a piece of code where you would like to use the local variable or the newly created one?

Comment: The only way I can envision this is by doing the following:  `new_val = {my_val = flatten(distinct(local.my_val))}`. But that's only if I understood what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarkoE I've mentioned the output format where I need only one unique entry of the region. Distinct was not working for map/tuples.

Comment: I don't know how it doesn't work, I got the result you want using the line from the previous comment. The only difference is the result is assigned to a new variable.

Answer (score 6):

that's an easy go if i understand correctly, that you want to keep distinct `region` and not distinct `(region,value)`:

```
locals {
  new_val = values(zipmap(local.my_val.*.region, local.my_val))
}
```

[`zipmap()`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/zipmap) creates a map of `region => {region,value}` for repeating `region` the map of the highest index of `local.my_val` is used (so later values overwrite previous ones).

`values()` then just extract the original maps.

You can also `revert()` the input and output list to keep lowest index.

If you care about `value` being unique just change the first parameter to `zipmap()` accordingly but you might need to convert it to a string.

If you want to keep distinct `(region,value)` (e.g. having same region with multiple values), then it gets a bit more tricky as you need to create a combined key:

```
locals {
  new_val = values(
    zipmap(
      [for m in local.my_val : join(":", [m.region, m.value])],
      local.my_val
    )
  )
}
```

i hope this helps ;)

Comment: +1 @mariux Thanks for the answer, what I need is to `eliminate the duplicates based on the value of the region key`. 
I will try your answer and let me update the outcome

Comment: I've updated the question. I need the corresponding object where the region is unique.

Comment: and you want to keep the first occurrence and not the last? @MadhukarHebbar

Comment: Yes, it can be first or last but it should be one per `region` key.