# how to merge list of maps in terraform

Tags: terraform

TF version is 1.0.11, I am trying to merge list of map variables, db_cluster_parameter_group_params is created in locals.tf, db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters is empty. I want to merge these 2, but it throws error.

In locals.tf:

```
db_cluster_parameter_group_params = [
  {name = "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay", value = "20"},
  {name = "max_wal_senders", value = "15", apply_method = "pending-reboot"}
  ]
```

In tfvar.tf:

```
variable "db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters" {
  description = "A list of DB cluster parameters to apply. Note that parameters may differ from a family to an other"
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = []
}

db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters = [
   {name = "vacuum_cost_limit", value = "1000"},   
   {name = "rds.logical_replication", value = "1", apply_method = "pending-reboot"}
]
```

Looking for db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters to be as follows:

```
db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters = [
  {name = "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay", value = "20"},
  {name = "max_wal_senders", value = "15", apply_method = "pending-reboot"},
   {name = "vacuum_cost_limit", value = "1000"},   
   {name = "rds.logical_replication", value = "1", apply_method = "pending-reboot"}
]
```

In the module I am trying to use merge to achieve desired results:

```
  db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters      = merge(local.db_cluster_parameter_group_params,var.db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters)

-- while running apply
│   on ../../main.tf line 123, in module "rds-aurora-postgresql":
│  123:   db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters      = merge(var.db_cluster_parameter_group_params,var.db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.db_cluster_parameter_group_params is list of map of string with 2 elements
│     │ var.db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters is a list of map of string, known only after apply
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the exact output you you want to produce? I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "merge a list of maps"; the `merge` function is only for producing a single map, which I don't think is what you want here because all of the input maps you showed seem to have the same keys.

Comment: updated the post with expected results, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using merge, you should use [concat](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/concat):

```
locals {
  db_cluster_parameter_group_params = [
    { name = "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay", value = "20" },
    { name = "max_wal_senders", value = "15", apply_method = "pending-reboot" }
  ]

  db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters = [
    { name = "vacuum_cost_limit", value = "1000" },
    { name = "rds.logical_replication", value = "1", apply_method = "pending-reboot" }
  ]

  db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters = concat(local.db_cluster_parameter_group_params, local.db_cluster_parameter_group_parameters)
}

output "db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters_output" {
  value = local.db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters
}
```

$ terraform apply
    
Outputs:

```
db_final_cluster_parameter_group_parameters_output = [
  {
    "name" = "autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay"
    "value" = "20"
  },
  {
    "apply_method" = "pending-reboot"
    "name" = "max_wal_senders"
    "value" = "15"
  },
  {
    "name" = "vacuum_cost_limit"
    "value" = "1000"
  },
  {
    "apply_method" = "pending-reboot"
    "name" = "rds.logical_replication"
    "value" = "1"
  },
]
```

Comment: this was helpful in case duplicates are present and need to be removed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925994/terraform-remove-duplicates-from-map-based-on-value